# ionic tabs and side menu routing possibilities

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, url-routing

I am trying to create an interface with tabbed navigation to navigate through different sections of an app, i.e. in the case of a news app as: Articles, Videos, Pictures. now along with that tabbed navigation I also want a side menu present for main categories relating to news articles, i.e. provinces, country, world, etc...

Now I have the tabbed navigation working along with routing but I cannot seem to get the routing working on the side menu.

Is it possible to have two abstract states in the view? Or is there a way to statically link the side menu to get it working?

I have seen a lot of questions and solutions to this problem however the solutions I have seen have the side menu and tabs using the same routing and linking to the same pages...

obviously I cannot understand the logic behind how one would implement this sort of setup and was wondering if anyone had any insight into this or has any links to articles that deal with this problem?

Comment: Hmmmm... ok apparently it cant be done and I should look at other alternatives.

Comment: did you manage to find any solution to this?